# Moving awning support column

Tags: roof, patio, support

I'm wondering if it would be possible to move this support column 1 meter to the left, so that it lines up with the start of the sliding doors instead of being in the middle of it. Would I need to add extra bracing/support?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Does it snow in your area, and if so how much? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how better to participate here.

Comment: Great pictures, but you only show parts of the awning. We could really use a picture of the whole area, as best as you can. I can't get any sense of where the pole is in relation to the rest of the structure. That's going to be key in getting an answer

Answer (score 1):

That design was very poorly thought out, but you undoubtedly know that already...

The structural members going along your house will have a maximum "span" width that they can support. Moving it to one side will decrease the span on the side that you move it to, but INCREASE 9it on the opposite side, and you will have no idea if that will be too much or not. If I had to guess though, it probably is, otherwise they would have made it wider to begin with.

So what I would do is to decrease the span on BOTH sides by adding ANOTHER support post, one on either side of the sliding doors. That way you have not increased the span anywhere and there is no doubt as to whether or not it is safe.

Answer (score 0):

Call a aluminum carport company .   See if they can add a header and two post to remove the one in the way.